# Migrating database from rails to django app in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, database, postgresql, heroku

I need to migrate my database from rails to django in heroku... Its a postgresql database for both on heroku. The issue is that the table names and field names are different on both databases for rails and django. Is there any plugin on heroku to help do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the models are not pre-defined in frameworks, I can not imagine how can there be any generic plugin to migrate data from one to another automatically.

Tthe migration problem between frameworks is quite different from, say, joomla to wordpress migration, where you have to deal with pre-defined tables.

in a FrameworkA > FrameworkB migration, what you need to do is to write custom code (in sql or python) to fetch data from your RoR project and insert into your Django project.